# Square roots of the unity (DIrichlet convolution)

Tags: analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-convolution

I am having a little trouble with this question.

Given an arithmetic function f, a “Dirichlet square root” of f is an
arithmetic function g such that $g ∗ g = f$. Prove by elementary techniques that the constant function $1$ has two Dirichlet square roots, of
the form $±g$, where $g$ is a multiplicative function, and find the values
of $g$ at prime powers.

I am trying to solve it using strong induction.

Since 
$$g(1)g(1)=1$$

we can define $g(1)=1$ and supposing $g(1), g(2), \dots, g(n-1)$ are well-defined, we must have
$$1 = 2g(1)g(n)+\Sigma_{d|n,1<d<n}g(d)g(n/d)$$

and so we can define $g(n)$.

It is easy to prove that $-g$ is also a square root of the unity, providing that $g$ is defined.

However, I am not sure if this "proof" is correct. It seems weird to me. And I don't know how to prove that $g$ is multiplicative.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the mistake.

Comment: Related: https://www.quora.com/Does-there-exist-a-function-f-such-that-f-ast-f-1-where-ast-denotes-the-Dirichlet-convolution